# opensocial newFetchPeopleRequest ignores parameters

Tags: javascript, opensocial

I'm trying to get person info woth specifies fields:

```
var params = {};
params[opensocial.DataRequest.PeopleRequestFields.PROFILE_DETAILS] = [
    opensocial.Person.Field.NICKNAME,
    opensocial.Person.Field.PROFILE_URL,
    opensocial.Person.Field.GENDER,
    opensocial.Person.Field.THUMBNAIL_URL,
    opensocial.Person.Field.ADDRESSES,
    opensocial.Person.Field.DATE_OF_BIRTH
];

params[opensocial.IdSpec.Field.USER_ID] = ids;
var idSpec = opensocial.newIdSpec(params);
var req = opensocial.newDataRequest();
req.add(req.newFetchPeopleRequest(idSpec), "profiles");
```

But on responce, whatever person fields I'm setting up, I always get same set of fields in return:

> displayName, id, isOwner, isViewer, nickname, thumbnailUrl

how to get requested fields?

**UPD:**
If this is important, social network I'm working with is yahoo mobage.

Comment: See https://docs.mobage.com/display/JPPC/opensocial.Person - there is no field `ADDRESS`, only `ADDRESSES`.

Comment: thx for responce. But that was juset literal mistake during this post typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are populating the `params` object but you are not actually using it in the request. You are merely using it in the `opensocial.newIdSpec()` call which gives you an `IdSpec` object. However, if you look at the [documentation of the `IdSpec` object](https://docs.mobage.com/display/JPPC/opensocial.IdSpec) - this one has only user-related fields, additional data is ignored. You should actually pass in `params` in your `newFetchPeopleRequest()` call:

```
 req.add(req.newFetchPeopleRequest(idSpec, params), "profiles");
```

For reference: [`opensocial.DataRequest.newFetchPeopleRequest` method](https://docs.mobage.com/display/JPPC/opensocial.DataRequest#opensocial.DataRequest-opensocial.DataRequest.newFetchPeopleRequest.1).